# How do I set a single pixel of an image in Slick2D?

Tags: java, image, slick

I would like to set an individual pixel in Slick (i.e `Image.setPixel(x, y, r, b, g)`) but I can't figure out how.

There is an `Image.setPixel` function but it doesn't take x and y coordinates. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're in luck.

In Slick2D, Image has a function called getGraphics, which will return you a Slick2D graphics context.

While the graphics context does not have a setPixel function, it does have a fillRect function that you can use to set a single pixel.

```
Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
g.setColor(color);
g.fillRect(x,y,1,1);
g.flush();//IMPORTANT!!!
```

I just tried this out myself, which is how I discovered the importance of the flush call.  Also check out the example ImageGraphcisTest.java in the Slick2D src folder.

Comment: A bit slow (when you are trying to set an 1000x1000 sized image with a different colour for each) but it works! Thanks! :)

Comment: In that case, I recommend only flushing once. (Amused by obious bathroom reference)

Comment: ahaha! lol, suprisingly I didn't even relate flush with a bathroom until now.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to make this from an `Image` object then you must:

- Get the texture with `img.getTexture()`
- Retrieve the inherent pixel data with `texture.getTextureData()`
- Parse the byte-array until you reach the pixel (x, y)
- Change the RGB value of this pixel

Comment: image(x, y) = image[y * width + x] ;)